# Xterm says it cannot find the 12x24 font

Tags: fonts, lts, xterm

I am running 18.04.4 LTS and today I see in nohup.out that my favorite xterm, which seems to be working, is complaining that the stock install does not configure the fonts correctly.  I do not want an xterm x fonts tutorial, I want the xterm to be defaulted into a traditional complete configuration so -fn 12x24 (I like the font bigger on fine pitch displays) does not complain.

```
xterm: cannot load font "-Sony-Fixed-bold-R-*-*-24-170-100-100-C-120-ISO8859-1"
xterm: cannot load font "-Sony-Fixed-medium-R-*-*-24-170-100-100-C-240-ISO10646-1"
xterm: cannot load font "-Sony-Fixed-bold-R-*-*-24-170-100-100-C-240-ISO10646-1"
```

Comment: The standard xfonts have all lower case names, and 12x24 is included in the standard set. The command xlsfonts lists them all

Comment: Have you tried a freetype font? I like it with `-fa default`and  `-fs 13` or smaller e.g. `-fs 10`.

Comment: I feel Ubuntu LTS should provide me with a proper configuration for -fn 12x24.  So, this is a bug report.  Why should I have to do anything to make a standard xterm run error free?